# Promise fetch returning Promise<void | T> instead of expected object

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I am doing a simple fetch using Typescript in a Class, which should return a promise, then I want to get the JSON response from this fetch. However, no matter what change I make, the function is always returning a `Promise<void | T>` which is ruining the type checking in my code.

```
export class ApiHelper {
    constructor() {     }

    public FetchFromPortal<T>(xyz: string) {

    ------ Other less relevant code -----------

        return fetch(url, options)
            .then((response) => this.CheckStatus(response))
            .then((response) => this.ParseJSON<T>(response))
            .then((response) => { 
                console.log(response);
                return response;
            })
            .catch((error: Error) => { console.log(error) });
    }

    private CheckStatus(response : Response) : Promise<Response> {
        if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
            return Promise.resolve(response);
        } else {
            let error = new Error(response.statusText);
            throw error;
        }
    }

    private ParseJSON<T>(response : Response) {
        return response.json() as Promise<T>;
    }
}
```

I'm then subsequently calling it like this:

```
let result = apiHelper.FetchFromPortal<T>(xyz);
```

According to Typescript, this is returning a `Promise<void | T>`. I've tried resolving the promise in the call like so:

```
let result = apiHelper.FetchFromPortal<T>(xyz).then(data => { return data });
```

Which should in theory resolve the `Promise` but this doesn't appear to be working.

Any reason why the promise isn't resolving to just the object?

Comment: "it's clearly the request object." --- it's impossible. Are you not confusing it with `console.log(response);`?

Comment: @zerkms It actually is. I had a rogue console.log and because of the asyncronous request I was misreading the order. It is a `Pending Promise` state at that point. 

I'll update my original question.

Comment: "but this doesn't appear to be working." --- what does this exactly mean? You cannot escape a promise. Once you're inside - you're doomed on using only a promise object.

Comment: @zerkms I'm not trying to escape it. I'm trying to resolve the promise and return the json object from the fetch. At the moment, no matter what I do, the Promise is always in a pending state.

Comment: "Promise is always in a pending state" --- before you claimed `console.log` outputs data.

Comment: @zerkms Which I then replied to you saying you were correct and I updated my question to accurately reflect the state.

Comment: If it's in pending state - it means `fetch` did not resolve it (yet). Has the http request completed?

Comment: The `void` in `Promise<void | T>` comes from your `catch`. If an error occurs, your code swallows it, effecting the `void`. That is, if there is an error, there is no resolved `T` value.

Answer (score 7):

> Any reason why the promise isn't resolving to just the object?

Here is the reason:

```
        })
        .catch((error: Error) => { console.log(error) });
```

When exception happens, this handler logs error to console and does not return anything. The compiler sees this and adds `void` union member to the return type.

Comment: I'm actually thinking the problem is my impatience and not logging these things correctly. It's returning the object after a second or so, but the caller has already continued processing code and isn't "Waiting" for the Promise to resolve.

Comment: "and isn't "Waiting"" --- it should not, that's the idea of asynchronicity.

Answer (score 2):

> Any reason why the promise isn't resolving to just the object?

Yes, promise resolution happens on some kind of "asynchronous space", the call will **always** just return a promise. The result of the promise is just forwarded through the `then()` chain and **never** returned to the caller (because they are asynchronous).

But I think you can have the behavior you are expecting by using `await`:

```
let result = await apiHelper.FetchFromPortal<T>(xyz);
```

Comment: The `await/async` is definitely a better approach. I believe this was actually entirely down to my impatience on the async call and was incorrectly debugging / using the Promise chain and had myself confused.Thank you for your answer.